# SQL Server - Cumulate awake time for devices from event summary

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I'm working on a SQL server (used by BMC) to grab the uptime of some devices.

I've got a query that display me results like this:

```
| DeviceName | EventDate               | EventType  |
| ---------- | ----------------------- | ---------- |
| 1          | 2021-02-15 08:06:12.000 | getting up |
| 1          | 2021-02-12 15:07:26.000 | going down |
| 2          | 2021-02-16 08:12:54.000 | getting up |
| 2          | 2021-02-12 15:43:00.000 | going down |
| 3          | 2021-02-15 07:47:42.000 | getting up |
| 3          | 2021-02-12 15:38:41.000 | going down |
| 4          | 2021-02-15 08:10:07.000 | getting up |
| 5          | 2021-02-18 06:41:40.000 | getting up |
| ...        | ...                     | ...        |
```

I would like to get a result that looks like that:

```
| DeviceName | TotalUpTime (min) |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1          | 16543             |
| 2          | 13639             |
| 3          | 13524             |
| 4          | 19235             |
| 5          | 12347             |
```

Here is my current query:

```
    SELECT 
        DeviceName, 
        EventDate, 
        EventType
    FROM **irrelevant complexe SELECT query**
    ORDER BY DeviceName, EventDate DESC
```

Any help would be **great**!!

Many thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

Ok, here's what worked for me:

```
SELECT 
    DeviceName,
    DATEDIFF(s, EventDate, EndTime)/60 AS [TotalUpTime (min)]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CASE WHEN EventType = 32 THEN EventDate END, 1, GETDATE())
        OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceName ORDER BY EventDate) AS EndTime
    FROM (
        **Irrelevant SELECT query**
    ) r
) s
WHERE EventType = 16 AND EndTime IS NOT NULL
```

Many thanks to @Charlieface whos response helped me a lot.

Hope this help someone someday, even if it's very specific.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    DeviceName,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, EventDate, EndTime) / 60000.0) AS [TotalUpTime (min)]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CASE WHEN EventType = 'going down' THEN EventDate END, 1, GETDATE()) OVER
            OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceName ORDER BY EventDate) AS EndTime
    FROM table
)
WHERE EventType = 'getting up' AND EndTime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DeviceName
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Charlieface ! I added your query to my code and tweaked it to make the syntax work. So when I execute it I got this error : `Column 's.DeviceName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` But when I execute only the part in your "FROM" I actually have a DeviceName column.

Comment: Forgot the `group by` sorry